# How can I get the sequence number of host entry defined in inventory file (Ansible)?

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I have an inventory file with two hosts defined as below

```
[testservers]
xx.xx.xx.106 ansible_ssh_user=johndoe
xx.xx.xx.138 ansible_ssh_user=johndoe
xx.xx.xx.141 ansible_ssh_user=johndoe
```

I want to use the sequence number of defined hosts inside the tasks.
Like for `xx.xx.xx.106` I should get the sequence 1, for `xx.xx.xx.141` I should get the sequence value as 3 since its the third entry.

How do I get this sequence number of host entry defined in inventory file without defining additional variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use standard Python's [index](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/list_index.htm) method.

Replace strings with variables below:

```
debug:
  msg: "{{ groups['testservers'].index('xx.xx.xx.141') + 1 }}"
```

(`+1` because you explicitly asked for a sequence from 1 to 3, but `index` starts with `0`)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a yaml inventory example using [@techraf's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47053407/ansible-how-do-i-get-the-sequence-number-of-host-entry-defined-in-inventory-fi/47567165#47567165):

```
    fpm:
      vars:
        Offset: 31
      hosts:
        fpm[01:10]-dc1:
            HostUnit: "{{groups['fpm'].index(inventory_hostname) + Offset}}"
            targethost: "prox0{{HostUnit|int % 2 + 1}}-dc1"
            ansible_ssh_host: "10.123.12.{{HostUnit}}"
```